# LINQ query to check same date in the list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of list complex object `itemofsamestartDate` means it has `itemofsamestartDate[0],itemofsamestartDate[1],itemofsamestartDate[2]....` and so on. itemofsamestartDate[i] has startDate property. I want to write a LINQ query to return `True` if all the list has same start date.

Below query, I tried -

```
var itemofsamestartDate = from aIndex in Enumerable.Range(0, itemOfSinglePrority.Count())
       from b in itemOfSinglePrority.Skip(aIndex + 1)
       let a = itemOfSinglePrority.ElementAt(aIndex)
       where a != b && a.StartDate == b.StartDate
       select new
       {
            object1 = a,
            object2 = b
       };
```

Now  I am checking if `itemofsamestartDate` count is greater than 0, then it has the same startdate, but above is working fine if I have list count of 2 only i.e. itemofsamestartDate[0] & itemofsamestartDate[1].

What should be a LINQ query to check if the list has same startdata(DateTime datatype).

Comment: It's unclear, do you want to **group** your items **by** `startDate`, or do you want to know **if** they all have the same `startDate` ?

Comment: I want to know if they all have same start date.

Comment: `bool allEqual = itemofsamestartDate.Count(x => x.StartDate == itemofsamestartDate[0].StartDate) == itemofsamestartDate.Count();` (well, you'd need to check if the list is not empty first)

Comment: What do you want to happen if the list is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A readable way of checking this can be :

```
bool allEqual=false;

if(itemofsamestartDate != null && itemofsamestartDate.Count()>0) {
    int countEqual = itemofsamestartDate
        .Count(x => x.StartDate == itemofsamestartDate[0].StartDate);
    int count = itemofsamestartDate.Count();

    allEqual = countEqual == count;
}
```

A less readable way :

```
bool allEqual=false;
if(itemofsamestartDate != null && itemofsamestartDate.Count()>0)
    allEqual = itemofsamestartDate.Count(x => x.StartDate == itemofsamestartDate[0].StartDate) == itemofsamestartDate.Count();
```

You could also group your list by `StartDate` and check if there is only one group.

Answer (score 0):

Class ItemOfStartDate has a property StartDate.
You have a sequence of objects of this class, and you want to know if all objects in this sequence have the same value for StartDate.

In other words, you want to know if there is only one value used for StartDate.

You didn't mention what you want if the sequence is empty. Let's assume that all StartDates in an empty list are equal

```
IEnumerable<ItemOfStartDate> myItems = ...
bool onlyOneStartDates = !myItems    // from every element in my sequence
   .Select(item => item.StartDate)  // take the value of StartDate
   .Distinct();                     // and remove duplicates
   .Skip(1)
   .Any();                          // true if we have more than 1 left
```

If you want to check uniqueness more often, consider creating an extension method:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static bool IsUnique<TSource, TKey>(this TSource source, 
        Func<TSource, TKey> propertySelector)
    {
         return !source.Select(propertySelector)
             .Distinct()
             .Skip(1)
             .Any();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<ItemOfStartDate> myItems = ...
bool onlyOneStartDates = IsUnique(item => item.StartDate);
```

If desired you can add an overload IEqualityComparer to use in [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx)